# Convergent or Divergent? $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{\lfloor \frac {n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1} \rfloor }\frac {ln{n}}{n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{\lfloor \frac {n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1} \rfloor }\frac {ln{n}}{n} $

$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+n^2(1+(-1)^n)} $

I know that both of them are disconverge absolutely. How can i prove that the serie is coverage or dicoverage?

Answer (score 1):

Hint for #1:

$$ \frac{n^3 +n+1}{3 n^2-1} = \frac{n}{3} + \frac{4n+3}{3(3n^2-1)} $$
the second term being small and positive ...